# Everything stays together. Im trying to get the search bar and the logo next to each other on the left side and extend the search to the end

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get the logo and search bar close together on the left side and extend the search bar to the right more. I dont know what else to do. Also I need to make a join and log in button to the right of everything. I also cant seem to get the submit button on the right side of the search field. [Basically needs to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUVp1.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

header>div {
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

nav {
  width: 600px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.blackHeart {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.searchmenu {
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: .3rem;
  display: right;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: black;
}

.search {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.463);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div>
    <div>
      <img class="blackHeart" src="images/black-heart.png" alt="black heart" />
      <span> Nifty Penguin Magic </span>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> npm Enterprise </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Products </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Solutions </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Resources </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Docs </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Support </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="searchmenu">
    <ul>
      <div>
        <img class="logo" src="images/npm-logo.png" alt="npm logo">
      </div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <div class="search-container">
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="search">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">Join Log In</a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this work? I cancelled all `float: right` from your code and replaced with `flexbox`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

header>div {
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

nav {
  width: 600px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.blackHeart {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.searchmenu {
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: .3rem;
  display: right;
}

.topnav, .searchContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  width: 18%;
  padding: 6px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: black;
}

.search {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.463);
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.searchmenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchDiv {
  width: 78%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.463);
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div>
    <div>
      <img class="blackHeart" src="images/black-heart.png" alt="black heart" />
      <span> Nifty Penguin Magic </span>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> npm Enterprise </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Products </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Solutions </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Resources </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Docs </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Support </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="searchmenu">
    <ul>
      <div>
        <img class="logo" src="images/npm-logo.png" alt="npm logo">
      </div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <div class="search-container">
          <form>
             <div class="searchDiv">
              <svg class="icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512">
                <g>
                <path d="m495,466.1l-119.2-119.2c29.1-35.5 46.5-80.8 46.5-130.3 0-113.5-92.1-205.6-205.6-205.6-113.6,0-205.7,92.1-205.7,205.7s92.1,205.7 205.7,205.7c49.4,0 94.8-17.4 130.3-46.5l119.1,119.1c8,8 20.9,8 28.9,0 8-8 8-20.9 0-28.9zm-443.2-249.4c-1.42109e-14-91 73.8-164.8 164.8-164.8 91,0 164.8,73.8 164.8,164.8s-73.8,164.8-164.8,164.8c-91,0-164.8-73.8-164.8-164.8z"/>
              </g>
              </svg>
 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" class="search">
            
             </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">Join Log In</a>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its for a school project i am doing. and just replacing it doesnt seem to solve my problem :/

Comment: What do you mean just replacing does not solve I resolved css bugs in your code to make it work, could you explain your requirements with more details?

Comment: Im sorry it actually did solve most of my problem.  Also how am i able to add a magnifying glass to the left of the search inside of the box as well as create a little space between the logo and the search

Comment: I edited my code and added also magnifying glass, for little space you can use margin or smaller width values for your elements. If it solved your problem, could you please choose it as accepted answer? @Jordan

Comment: sure of course. I added an image of how its suppose to look like and im still not getting it to look like that on the original post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are going with floats also i have made sime changes to your overall html and css you can compare with your code.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        font-family: "Poppins";
      }

      header > .firstnav {
        padding: 12.5px 25px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
      }

      nav {
        width: 600px;
      }

      nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }

      nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

      .blackHeart {
        width: 20px;
        margin-right: 1rem;
      }

      .searchmenu {
        padding: 12.5px 25px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .logo {
        width: 50px;
        margin-left: 0.3rem;
      }
      .searchmenu form {
        position: relative;
      }
      .searchmenu form svg {
        width: 33px;
        background: beige;
        padding: 7px;
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
        height: 34px;
        top: -1px;
        left: 29px;
      }

      .searchmenu input[type="text"] {
        padding: 6px 35px;
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.463);
        margin-left: 30px;
        width: 1050px;
      }

      .searchmenu button {
        padding: 6px;
        background: red;
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
      }

      .searchmenu ul li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px 0;
      }
      .searchmenu ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 15px;
      }
      .searchmenu ul {
        display: flex;
      }
      .join {
        border: 1px solid grey;
      }
```

and your HTML

```
<header>
      <div class="firstnav">
        <div>
          <img
            class="blackHeart"
            src="images/black-heart.png"
            alt="black heart"
          />
          <span> Nifty Penguin Magic </span>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> npm Enterprise </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Products </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Solutions </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Resources </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Docs </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Support </a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="searchmenu">
        <div>
          <img class="logo" src="images/npm-logo.png" alt="npm logo" />
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="topnav"> -->
        <!-- <div class="search-container"> -->
        <form>
          <svg
            class="icon"
            version="1.1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 512 512"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            enable-background="new 0 0 512 512"
          >
            <g>
              <path
                d="m495,466.1l-119.2-119.2c29.1-35.5 46.5-80.8 46.5-130.3 0-113.5-92.1-205.6-205.6-205.6-113.6,0-205.7,92.1-205.7,205.7s92.1,205.7 205.7,205.7c49.4,0 94.8-17.4 130.3-46.5l119.1,119.1c8,8 20.9,8 28.9,0 8-8 8-20.9 0-28.9zm-443.2-249.4c-1.42109e-14-91 73.8-164.8 164.8-164.8 91,0 164.8,73.8 164.8,164.8s-73.8,164.8-164.8,164.8c-91,0-164.8-73.8-164.8-164.8z"
              />
            </g>
          </svg>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search.."
            name="search"
            class="search"
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- </div> -->
        <ul>
          <li class="join"><a href="#">Join</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
```